# Logs are not shown when the webapp is triggered by doGet

Tags: forms, logging, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm currently trying to write a form in HTML that passes its input to a spreadsheet. I did it as shown in the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRQvySxaCW0&list=PLv9Pf9aNgemt82hBENyneRyHnD-zORB3l.
The problem is that the Logger in addInfo() function isn't working when the button is clicked (In the Logs is no "Hey" when the button got clicked).

My Code.gs (Google Apps Script) file:

```
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");

}

function addInfo(){
  Logger.log("Hey");
}
```

My index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="btn">Klick mich</button>

    <script>

    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click",doStuff);

    function doStuff(){
      google.script.run.addInfo();
    }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is anyone knowing why it is not working like that?
I appreciate your help.

Best regards,
Max

Comment: Try `console.log()` instead

Comment: Where are you checking the logs? Add an alert or something to `doStuff()` to see if it is executing on the client side at least. Does the browser console logs show anything?

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan I check the logs via the google apps script ide. On the upper menu I click on "View" then on "Logs" (as seen in Screenshot 6: https://filebin.net/2d36ede1h919rxc9). But it says everytime "No functions have been run in this editor session."... I don't really know how I can add an alert to the function to check if it was running.

Comment: Logs for `doGet` and other triggers can’t be seen from the IDE. Go to the script dashboard and view the execution logs from there.

Answer (score 2):

## Issue

The logs of triggers like `doGet()` cannot be seen from the **Apps Script IDE Logger**.

## Solution

Follow these steps to achieve what you are aiming for:

1. Instead of `Logger.log` use `console.log`.
2. In your script editor go to **Resources  -> Cloud Platform Project**.
3. Select the project you want to associate the script with. For that you will need to have previously created a project in the [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-projects) and use its project’s number.
4. Once you have your script linked with the project, go to **View -> Stackdrive Logging** and there you will be able to see the console logs of the script including the ones in the trigger functions.

For more information regarding this process, [check this post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/stackdriver-logging-for-google-apps) where they explain more extensively the use of the Stackdrive Logger for Apps Script.

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)

Answer (score 0):

I ran it as a dialog like this:

[image]

Comment: Unrelated but how did you create this GIF? I have never been able to make one that maintains this quality/resolution while still being so small.